# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource cannot be found

Tags: java, apache-karaf

I'm using Karaf 4.4.3 with Postgres JDBC 42.6.0 and trying to create PGSimpleDataSource
`PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();` but get exception while Karaf starting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource cannot be found by ***`. What might be the reason and how can I fix it?

I have installed the following features but it didn't help

```
jdbc/1.5.5, \
pax-jdbc/1.5.5, \
pax-jdbc-postgresql/1.5.5, \
pax-jdbc-config/1.5.5, \
```

Comment: A full stack trace would be more helpful... Where do you try to create `PGSimpleDataSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I added javax.sql to Karaf config.properties file.

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = \
    com.sun.*, \
    javax.sql, \
    javax.naming, \
    javax.transaction, \
    javax.transaction.xa, \
    # other default stuff goes here
```